# How viewChild can get elements that added with js in angular2?

Tags: typescript, angular, datatables, viewchild

If a HTML element has been added to the DOM(for example after click on button),  How can we access this element? viewChild can't see that.

**Update 1:** More description

I've used jquery datatable ([jquery.dataTables definitelyTyped version](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/jquery.dataTables)). Base on [this](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html) link, I can add new column and define html inside that. I wrote this code :

```
           columnDefs: [
                    {
                        render: function (data, type, row) {
                            return `
                                  <a href="admin/edituser/` + row.UserId+ `" class="btn btn-outline btn-circle btn-sm green"><i class="fa fa-edit" > </i> Edit </a>`+
                                 `<a [routerLink]="['Delete']" class="btn btn-outline btn-circle btn-sm red"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" > </i> Delete </a>
                                            `;
                        },
                        targets: 5
                    },
                ],
```

[image]

With Chrome Developer tools I see this :
[image]

First anchor tag works but with href, not routerLink.

Second anchor tag doesn't work because angular directives didn't complie to href.

I tried to use DynamicComponentLoader to compile it, and changed code like this:
[image]

But I can't access #target element with viewChild.(I want to change it with another component by loadNextToLocation). I think this isn't optimize way to get good result.

I want to use routerLink with commands buttons inside jquery datatable.

Could you please help me in the right direction to solve this?

Thank you in advance.

## solution :

If you want to add HTML to DOM with javascript or some callback function first determine a tag from template that can be a parent for those element(s) in future.

1. Add template variable to this parent element.(#target for example)

   ```
                   <th> Email</th>
                   <th> Date </th>
                   <th> Phone </th>
                   <th> Commands</th>


               </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody #target></tbody>
           <tfoot>
               <tr>

                   <th>  </th>
                   <th>  </th>
                   <th>  </th>
                   <th>  </th>

               </tr>
           </tfoot>
       </table>
   ```
2. Then add a simple class and a simple attribute to your html code(This code is generated after page compiled with angular,Also you can write some code with typescript or javascript to generate html).

   ```
      columnDefs: [
                   {
                       render: function (data, type, row) {
                           return `
                                `<a date-id="` + row.UserId + `" class="editbtn btn btn-outline btn-circle btn-sm red"> Edit</a>
                                `;
                       },
                       targets: 5
                   },
               ],
   ```
3. Now import and inject these sources to your component:

   ```
       import {ViewChild, Renderer} from '@angular/core';
   ```

   and :

   ```
       constructor(private renderer: Renderer, private router: Router)
   ```
4. Define a viewChild variable in your component class:

   ```
       @ViewChild('target') target;
   ```
5. Write a function like this :

   ```
   public AfterEverything() {
          var el: HTMLElement = this.target.nativeElement;//Make an Element Object
          console.log(el);
          var commands: NodeListOf<Element> = el.getElementsByClassName('editbtn');//Find Element Object to get all elements with a specefic class
          console.log(commands);
          for (var i = 0; i < commands.length; i++) {
              //Loop for add event or style
              console.log(commands[i]);
              //Sample event(Click for routing)
              this.renderer.listen(commands[i], 'click', (event: Event) => {
                  var thisid = event.srcElement.getAttribute("date-id");//Get value from element
                  console.log(thisid);
                  this.router.parent.navigate(['EditUser', { id: thisid }]);//Use value to make routeLink
                  console.log(event.srcElement.innerHTML);
              });
              this.renderer.setElementStyle(commands[i], 'backgroundColor', 'yellow');//for change color(just sample)
          }
   ```

   }
6. You must find best place to call this function,for example, ajax data callback is one choice and call AfterEverything() inside that. You can call this function inside ngAfterViewInit().

**Note that sometimes a delay of several seconds is necessary to ensure that all new elements are created.**

Comment: How do you add it?

Comment: For example please see this : https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html. We can use render function to add some text (like HTML) inside a column. Imagine that we want to change elements that created with this function.

Comment: The solution you added to your answer is basically the same as the one I explained with `ElementRef`. You don't start from the components host element but a more specific element like explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template/35209681#35209681

Answer (score 2):

If you add HTML dynamically (like `[innerHTML]="someHtml"`), then you can use direct DOM access (frowned upon in Angular2) by injecting `ElementRef` and using `ElementRef.nativeElement.querySelector...`

If the HTML is generated using `*ngFor` you can add template variables and query for these elements like

```
<div *ngFor="let x of y" #someVar></div>
```

and then in the component class

```
@ViewChildren('someVar') elements;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.elements);
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I couldn't solve my problem.I Updated my question with more details.

Comment: Template variables don't work when the HTML is added dynamically. Your question doesn't show how the HTML added. You need to use the `ElementRef` approach.

Comment: I found a solution and added it to my question.